# Advanced helper methods in spock framework

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I use Spock framework. I am aware of helper methods which can encapsulate logic from `then:` blocks. What I need is to reuse a few lines of code between different feature methods in the same class. Those lines of code contain `when:` an `then:` blocks, e.g.:

```
def "myFeatureMethod"() {
    given:
    ...

    when:
    ...

    then:
    ...

    myHelperMethod
}

private void myHelperMethod() {
    when:
    ...

    then:
    ...
}
```

From what I understand, this is not currently possible with Spock. Is there any workaround available to achieve the same?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to have `when:`, `then:`, etc. blocks in helper methods, they should only be used in feature methods.

Answer (score 0):

First lets make sure we understand the meaning of each block in the Spock Framework.

The using of the **when:** is for the condition we wish to check.

The using of the **then:** is for the result we wish to get.

for the same **when:** block with same conditions the **then:** block should behave with the same result.

The best practice is to omit one of the **then:** block (probably you can find one of them as irrelevant after the first checking).
After omitting the irrelevant **then:** block you can merge the 2 **when:** blocks remains.

Another option is to have a cleaning method in the end of each Spock test.

That can be done in 2 ways:

1. Using a common method such as:

> ```
> def cleanup() {}        // run after every feature method
>
> def cleanupSpec() {}    // run after the last feature method
> ```

2. Using a  **cleanup:** block inside the relevant tests. The clean up should hold the **when:** 
   block from the **myHelperMethod()** while the **then:** block should be omitted cause the checking should be not so important for the checking.

Answer (score 0):

Spock now does allow helper methods in `then:` blocks - from the [documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_helper_methods):

```groovy
def "offered PC matches preferred configuration"() {
  when:
  def pc = shop.buyPc()

  then:
  matchesPreferredConfiguration(pc)
}

def matchesPreferredConfiguration(pc) {
  pc.vendor == "Sunny"
  && pc.clockRate >= 2333
  && pc.ram >= 4096
  && pc.os == "Linux"
}
```

Or with nicer error messages:

```groovy
void matchesPreferredConfiguration(pc) {
  assert pc.vendor == "Sunny"
  assert pc.clockRate >= 2333
  assert pc.ram >= 4096
  assert pc.os == "Linux"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to reuse the **then:** block it means that you want multiple unit tests that check the same thing. This is an anti-pattern as it leads to code that is hard to maintain.

You should centralize your common unit test code in a single test method and use [parameterized tests](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html) if you want the same test logic but for different "examples".

Comment: You made an incorrect assumption I use Spock for unit testing. That's not the case, I use it also for e2e tests where certain test steps can be shared and it has nothing to do with broken test design.